# How fetch_assoc know that you want the next row from the table?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

If we would have code like this:

```
$result = $conn->query('SELECT username FROM users');
$row1 = $result->fetch_assoc();
echo $row1['username'], '<br>';
$row2 = $result->fetch_assoc();
echo $row2['username'], '<br>';
```

Second echo would show username from second row in table, but why? How fetch_assoc() know that you want the next row in return. Does it have some built-in counter that counts how many times it was called?

Comment: Every time you `fetch_assoc()` it returns the current row and **automatically advances** to to the next row.

Comment: There is a manual on this http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php, did you not read through it?

Comment: i have been wondering this for so long. i was having such a hard time understanding this method because it seemed to work like magic. thank you for asking it!

Comment: also @FunkFortyNiner that manual says nothing about the pointer automatically advancing. w3schools doesn't mention it either. in fact this is the only place i've seen that has an explanation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It keeps a pointer into the list of rows returned. When the query returns data (i.e. when the result object is created), it retrieves all the rows returned by the query.

```
> row1 foo bar
  row2 baz boo
  row3 tst tmp
```

When you call `fetch_assoc`, the row the pointer points to is returned, and the pointer is advanced:

```
return_val = (row1, foo, bar)
increment pointer

  row1 foo bar
> row2 baz boo
  row3 tst tmp

return return_val
```

This is repeated until there is nothing more to return. `fetch_assoc` then returns null forever.

The last part allows you to use it in a `while` loop automagically:

```
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    // do something with $row
}
```

When `fetch_assoc` returns null, the while loop terminates and execution continues outside the loop - and the complete result set has been read.

Answer (score 0):

1. A while loop runs unless the defined condition doesn't evaluate to false.
2. The **fetch_assoc()** function would place its pointer towards the next row once the previous row has been fetched. When it runs out of rows, it returns null, and null always evaluates false, and thus, the while loop stops its execution and the program continues.